# How to cast function to comparer in C#

Tags: c#, lambda-calculus

I have to sort list that way so I have to use function in variable

```
Func<Elem, Elem, int> w = (elem1, elem2) => DateTime.Compare(elem1.Date, elem2.Date);
list.Sort(w);
```

How can I cast function to comparer?

Comment: What Class is the list?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Comparison<Elem>` class or create class that implements `IComparer<Elem>`

```
list.Sort(new Comparison<Elem>((v1, v2) => DateTime.Compare(v1.Date, v2.Date)));
```

IComparer implementation

```
public class ElemComparer : IComparer<Elem>
{
    public int Compare(Elem x, Elem y)
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date);
    }
}
```

using ElemComparer

```
list.Sort(new ElemComparer());
```

Comment: `DateTime.Compare` implictly converts to a `Comparison<DateTime>` so you can just use `list.Sort(DateTime.Compare)`.

Comment: @Lee Elem is not DateTime. You can use DateTime.Compare only if you need sort list of DateTimes, but that is `List<Elem>`

Answer (score 0):

For any type you can self implement :

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Sort((e1, e2) =>
{ // Do compensation based on e1 and e2, and return -1, 0, 1
    return 0;
});
```

Some types have default Comparer, like this :

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list.Sort(Comparer<DateTime>.Default);
```

or :

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list.Sort(DateTime.Compare);
```

Comment: List of Elem `List<Elem>` should be sorted